# Ajax não funciona no Internet explorer 6

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX, JSON E PHP</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <select name="secoes" id="secoes" style="font-weight:bold;width:100%">
    <option>Selecione...</option>
        <option value="25" id="25">Hortifrutti</option>
        <option value="15" id="15">Peixaria</option>
    </select>       



    <select id="itens" name="itens" style="width:100%; font-weight:bold;">
    <option>Selecione...</option>
    <option value=""></option>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#secoes').change(function(){
        $('#itens').load('dados.php?secao='+$('#secoes').val() );

    });
        $('#itens').change(function(){
            var Valor = $('#itens').val();
            if(Valor != ''){
        $('#tabela').load('dados.php?ean='+$('#itens').val() );
            }
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Retoro PHP

```
<head>
    <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<? require_once('bd.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    //header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $SecaoPadrao = $_GET['secao'];
    $eanselecionado = $_GET['ean'];
    if($secao!= ''){
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ConferenciaCeasa where secao ='$SecaoPadrao' and ForaLinha!='*' order by descricao asc");
        echo "<option>Selecione...</option>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['ean']."'>".$row['descricao']."</option>";
            }
    }elseif($eanselecionado!= ''){
        $query = mysql_query ("select TaraQuantidade,TaraTroca from ConferenciaCeasa WHERE ean like '$eanselecionado'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<input type='text' style='width:100%;display:<?echo $mostra;?>' value='".$row['TaraQuantidade']."' id='tara-quantidade' name='tara-quantidade' onblur='CalculaCaixa();' onfocus='this.select()'></input>";
            }
    }



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Curiosidade: qual a sua necessidade de ainda utilizar IE6?

Comment: Difícil (senão impossível) ver pessoas ainda usando o IE6.... Funciona mais ou menos como o Safari no windows, não tem muito sentido  tentar ficar ajustando em todos os navegadores, ainda mais os antigos, um site que seja 100% compatível em todos os browser é algo inalcançável por que a [lista de browsers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_navegadores) existentes, e a lista de implementações diferentes é enorme

Comment: Não posso falar pelo autor da pergunta, mas até pouco tempo atrás (3 meses) as empresas de call center que eu trabalhei usavam o IE6 como único navegador, além do antigo querido windows xp. Tem muita empresa pré-histórica por ai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do *jQuery 2* em diante não há mais suporte para os navegadores IE 6/7/8 e talvez algumas coisas não funcionem no Android 2 e Internet Explorer 9, como dito em https://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

Para resolver você pode tentar o **jQuery 1.x**, baixe estes:

- Compactado (para produção): https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
- Não compactado: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

Deve ficar assim:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#secoes').change(function(){
        $('#itens').load('dados.php?secao='+$('#secoes').val() );

    });
        $('#itens').change(function(){
            var Valor = $('#itens').val();
            if(Valor != ''){
        $('#tabela').load('dados.php?ean='+$('#itens').val() );
            }
    });

});
</script>
```

Note que você pode acompanhar o update do jQuery1 aqui: https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x

Comment: Muito Obrigado Brother !!!!! resolveu meu problema.